# Avoid sql-drop or sql-sync drush commands in a particular environment

Tags: 7, drush

I'm syncronizing databases form stage to local environments with drush commands like:

```
drush @dev sql-drop
drush @stage @dev sql-sync
```

How can I protected that the @stage server reject to drop or sync its database like:

```
drush @dev @stage sql-sync
drush @dev sql-drop
```

I think this is a common problem, maybe there is some params that can be set in drushrc.php file. How can I manage that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is best done with a policy file.  See [policy.drush.inc](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/policy.drush.inc), which has an example policy prohibiting overwriting a production server.

The example could be expanded to perhaps check for patterns in the destination parameter (any alias containing 'prod'), etc.